# What kind of helmets are these?

Tags: warhammer-40k, object-identification

I've been troubled by helmets recently. Namely, artwork of Horus leading the Sons of Horus into battle. The image shows all sorts of variations of space marine helmets ranging from the Mk4 helmet to the Mk6 helmet. This marine  sitting in the bottom corner caught my attention though:

[image: space marine]

I don't recognize the helmet that they are wearing at all. At first I thought it was like the helmet the khornate berzerkers wear (like below)....

[image: khornate]

....but quickly realized the differences and that even then, I don't actually know what type of helmet the berzerker wears.

Neither helmet appears in the different Marks of Space Marine power armor (seen below).

[image: mark]

**What version of power armor do these helmets belong to or are they their own little special version?**

Bonus: Do they offer the user anything special compared to other helmets?

Comment: I'm seeing several Mandalorians, at least one Bionicle Mask of Shielding, and one Optimus Prime.

Comment: I hope your helmet trouble is cleared up, and that the ointment works.

Comment: They look like Mk2 "Crusade" helmets to me (or variants of that style, if you prefer.)  Unless I'm mistaken, that would also be about the right era for the Horus Heresy and thus appropriate for Chaos Marine helmets.

Comment: Is it just me or does the first picture look like Fulgore from Killer Instinct? http://www.game-art-hq.com/93593/fulgore-from-killer-instinct-game-art-gallery-character-overview/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you were right about the second one - it does look like Khornate Berserkers helmet that comes from the original World Eaters one:

[image]

Please notice the characteristic horns on the sides and the three slits on the helmet.

While I can't find any description of the name (Forgerowld simply calls it "[World Eaters Legion Mark II helmet](https://www.forgeworld.co.uk/en-AU/World-Eaters-Legion-MKII-Upgrade-Set-Veteran-Heads)", the popular theory suggest its a homage to the helmet Angron wore as a gladiator.

The one in the first picture looks suspiciously close either to Vindicare Assasin helmet
[image]

or to... Imperial Guard one:
[image]

But most probably its just an unique helmet.

Answer (score 2):

According to the novels (i.e. as recently as Master of Mankind), variations of the standard mark 3-5 armour were numerous. Even the Custodians had not seen every slight alteration because it was highly dependent on the custom instructions each legion gave their supporting forge worlds.

Case in point, the Beserker variation is a novel helmet style to various Terra's protectors as of 5 years into the heresy.